# Translating batch to script (Windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

totally new to scripting, trying to translate a piece of batch script to go into a script.

The batch parts are commented. I am trying to move all files that are alone in a directory up one directory, deleting the empty directory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
strDir = "j:\"

set FSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objDir = FSO.GetFolder(strDir)
getInfo objDir

Sub getInfo(pCurrentDir)

   For Each aItem In pCurrentDir.SubFolders
      getInfo aItem
   Next

   if pCurrentDir.Files.Count = 1 then
      if pCurrentDir.Subfolders.Count = 0  then


'    Move all files inside the subdirectory up one level.
    move /s %%d\*.* %%d\..\.

'   Delete the directory
    RD /y %%d

      end if
   end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strDir = "j:\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objDir = FSO.GetFolder(strDir)
getInfo objDir
Sub getInfo(pCurrentDir)
    WScript.Echo pCurrentDir
    For Each aItem In pCurrentDir.SubFolders
        getInfo aItem
    Next

    If pCurrentDir.Files.Count = 1 Then 
        If pCurrentDir.Subfolders.Count = 0  Then
            ' Move all files inside the subdirectory up one level.          
            For Each f In FSO.GetFolder(pCurrentDir).Files
                f.Move f.ParentFolder.ParentFolder & "\"
            Next 
            ' Delete the directory
            FSO.DeleteFolder pCurrentDir,True
        End If
    End If 
End Sub
```